# Average start up time for Macbook Pro running Lion?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

I have a new MacBook Pro 13 inch 2.4GHz and I am noticing that the start up timeis about 60 seconds from power on to launching Safari.

Is this an average start up time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your start up time is dependent on how fast your hard drive is, how full it is, and how your OS is running. If you're running a normal 5400 RPM drive with around 50% of the storage space filled, 60 seconds is about normal. A few things you could do to help this out are:

## Reset the SMC

1. Shut down your MacBook Pro
2. Plug in the MagSafe adapter and make sure it is charging
3. Simultaneously press the <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + Power buttons and hold them for about 10 seconds. Let go after that.
4. Restart your Mac (and move on to the following suggestion):

## Reset the PRAM

1. Press the power button to start up your MacBook Pro
2. Hold down the following keys:<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> until you hear the start up chime sound twice.
3. Let go and boot normally.

## Disk Repair

1. Open Disk Utility from `/Applications/Utilities`
2. Select your startup volume, probably named "Macintosh HD"
3. Click on **Repair Disk**

## Permissions Repair

1. Open Disk Utility from `/Applications/Utilities`
2. Select your startup volume, probably named "Macintosh HD"
3. Click on **Repair Disk Permissions**

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It should be about half or less.

Try this:

- **[PRAM reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379)**

  1. (Re-)start the computer.
  2. Press and hold the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys. 
     You must press this key combination before the gray screen appears.
  3. Hold the keys down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for the second time.
- **[SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964)**

  - The procedure depends on what kind of Mac you have. Follow the link and go to the section *Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC)* to see what you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

MacBook Pro 2011
15 seconds restart time
After having my Logic Board replaced it restarted in 45 seconds but that was quickly fixed with, during power up, OPT + CMD + r + p and wait for second chime. This resets the PRAM.
It is again restarting at 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

60 seconds is rather long (although mine doesn't do much better...). And their seems to be a lot of people suffering from this problem... (on [Macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1194587) and [the Apple Discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3195502?start=0&tstart=0) are some reports of people with problems like you).

You could boost your Mac performance if you like. [Here](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10332743-263.html) is a good tutorial how to boost up your Mac Startup process.

And if that doesn't help you out, [here is a wiki](http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Speed_Up_Your_Mac) where they go something more in depth about the start up process.